# How to solve this error ImproperlyConfigured: settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. Please supply the ENGINE value.

Tags: django

have written a script named "installcms.sh" and i placed it /root

This is my script

```
apt-get install python-setuptools python-imaging >> installcms.log 2>&1
easy_install pip >> installcms.log 2>&1
pip install django django-cms south django-appmedia >> installcms.log 2>&1
django-admin.py startproject djangocmsproject >> installcms.log 2>&1
cd djangocmsproject
rm settings.py
rm urls.py
cp /root/settings.py settings.py >> installcms.log 2>&1
cp /root/urls.py urls.py >> installcms.log 2>&1
mkdir templates
cd templates
cp /root/example.html example.html >> installcms.log 2>&1
cd ..
python manage.py syncdb --all >> installcms.log 2>&1
python manage.py migrate --fake >> installcms.log 2>&1
python manage.py runserver >> installcms.log 2>&1
```

### When i try to execute my script using the command "/root/installcms.sh"

I am getting this error

```
ImproperlyConfigured: settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. Please
supply the ENGINE value. Check settings documentation for more details.
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing the most likely error is that your `settings.py` is incorrect; specifically, one or more of the databases defined in the `DATABASES` dict is missing the `ENGINE` configuration value.

Take a look at the [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#databases) for an example of what the database configuration should look like.